# Recursive model relationship with conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, query-builder

I have this scope in model Task, i want eager load these Task analogues by with() method (i now how do recursive relationship using parent_id, but this is not the case). Example `Task::query()->with('analogues')`:

```
public function scopeAnalogues(Builder $builder, Task $task): Builder
{
    $themeIds = $task
        ->themes
        ->pluck('id')
        ->toArray();

    return $builder
        ->where('id', '!=', $task->id)
        ->where('task_line_id', $task->task_line_id)
        ->whereHas('themes', function (Builder $builder) use ($themeIds) {
            $builder->whereIn('themes.id', $themeIds);
        });
}
```

I do this, but it is do not work, because $this not working in relationship context.

```
public function analogues(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'id')
        ->where('id', '!=', $this->id)
        ->whereHas('themes', function ($query) {
            $query->whereIn('themes.id', $this->themes->pluck('id')->toArray());
        });
}
```

Comment: the relationship method is being called on a new non-existing model instance, so there are no attributes or relations, etc ... eloquent only needs to call this method to get the returned builder object to then get multiple records records at once ( no N+1 )